# Approximation of piecewise linear function by smooth function

Tags: functions, reference-request, special-functions, approximation, approximation-theory

I am reading a paper: [Target enumeration via integration over planar
sensor networks](https://www.math.upenn.edu/~ghrist/preprints/rsszurich.pdf)

And I would like to know if there is any reference which deals with approximating piecewise linear functions defined in $\mathbb{R}^n$ by smooth ones. Maybe that reference could cover the procedure, the errors...
Even a reference for the case $n=2$ would be nice.

My question arises as I would like to apply some techniques from Morse theory but I have a piecewise linear interpolation of some counting functions.

Thanks in advance and any help would be appreciated

Comment: Convolution / mollifier?

Comment: The problem with this is that there will exist an infinite number of smooth functions that will "approximate" a given piece-wise function in some way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that piecewise linear functions defined on $\mathbb R^n$ for n>1 would have to be discontinuous. Consider n=2, the plane tiles wouldn't meet across grid cell edges. Unless you actually mean bi-linear patches.

Anyway, if you want to blend the local pieces smoothly into a globally smooth function, take a look at [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1206.0513) that shows how to build a curvature continuous surface using tensor product B-splines and partition of unity.